# Remove elements from a single column of a dataframe by a pair-wise comparison

Tags: r, for-loop, nested, sapply

I have the following vectors extracted from a dataframe

```
parent<-c(119.04832, 120.34873, 405.80245, 635.80934)
product<-c(119.04838, 800.56437, 361.87349, 582.09567, 444.65898, 286.08075)
```

I would like to remove all the elements "almost equal" only from the product array. A nested for loop could be an option. Something like this:

```
limit<-0.0001
for(i in 1:length(parent)){
 for(j in 1:length(product)){
  if(abs(parent[i]-product[j]<=limit)){
    replicate<-rbind(replicate,product[j])
    } else {not_replicate<-rbind(not_replicate, product[j])
  }
 }
}
```

So, what I expect to have is a new vector

```
>replicate
[1] 800.56437, 361.87349, 582.09567, 444.65898, 286.08075
```

Is there any way smarter and faster than this? For example something which implies the use of sapply or ifelse?

P.S.
A larger test case could be:

```
parent<-c(225.08619,236.09266.16304,267.14706,270.10044,277.18305,282.15796,355.15658,496.23987,238.11061,239.06545,252.08988,252.08988,
,369.17223,413.25640,467.30356,551.39344,748.50853) 

product<-c(300.02900,227.10570,341.17340,305.17360,241.12110,369.18980,269.13730,347.10386,373.19980,357.18960,266.16307,233.19210,269.13720,357.18860,269.13740,406.24220,305.17370,405.22580,157.08490,157.08520,157.09490,169.08480,169.12130,181.12060,
187.09550,199.11050,209.11600,225.08620,227.12690)
```

Comment: Maybe something like `product[!as.logical(colSums(abs(outer(parent, product, "-")) <= limit))]`? can you share some other test cases?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 impressive

Comment: @AeonRed Please edit your question in order to add to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
parent <- c(119.04832, 120.34873, 405.80245, 635.80934)
product <- c(119.04838, 800.56437, 361.87349, 582.09567, 444.65898, 286.08075)
limit <- 0.0001
```

I'd use `outer`:

```
product[!as.logical(colSums(abs(outer(parent, product, "-")) <= limit))]
# [1] 800.5644 361.8735 582.0957 444.6590 286.0808
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply` instead of a for loop

`product[!as.logical(apply(sapply(product, function(x) abs(x - parent) <= 0.0001), 2L, sum))]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using the dplyr package's `near` function:

```
parent<-c(119.04832, 120.34873, 405.80245, 635.80934)
product<-c(119.04838, 800.56437, 361.87349, 582.09567, 444.65898, 286.08075)

library(dplyr)
#create matrix of matches between parent and product
result<-sapply(parent, function(x){near(x, product, tol=0.0001)})
#find rows where there is at least one match
toremove<-which(rowSums(result)>0)
#remove unwanted values
product[-toremove]
```